# How to use didSelectViewController with two different controllers?

Tags: ios, methods, duplicates, appdelegate

I want to use method didSelectViewController in my appDelegate.m with two viewControllers (linked by a TabBarController).

When I copy the first method (which works fine alone) and paste it just under. I change the name of the viewController but error message "duplicate declaration of method" appears however.

Any ideas to resolve this ?

What I have :

```
- (void)tabBarController:(TBControllerViewController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(FoodViewController *)viewController {
    viewController.caloriesDepensees = tabBarController.caloriesTB;
}
```

What I want to have without errors :

```
- (void)tabBarController:(TBControllerViewController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(FoodViewController *)viewController {
    viewController.caloriesDepensees = tabBarController.caloriesTB;
}

- (void)tabBarController:(TBControllerViewController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(DrinksViewController *)viewController {
    viewController.caloriesDepenseesDrinks = tabBarController.caloriesTB;
}
```

**EDIT :**
Martin R, I have followed your advice and here is my code :

```
- (void)tabBarController:(TBControllerViewController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    if(tabBarController.selectedIndex == 0) {
        DrinksViewController *dvc = (DrinksViewController *)viewController;
        dvc.caloriesImportesD = tabBarController.caloriesTB;
    } else if (tabBarController.selectedIndex == 1) {
        FoodViewController *fvc = (FoodViewController *)viewController;
        fvc.caloriesDepensees = tabBarController.caloriesTB;
    }
}
```

But only my "(tabBarController.selectedIndex == 1)" command works.
I have checked viewController's index with this method so I'm sure DrinksViewController's index is 0 :

```
index = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers indexOfObject:self];
    NSLog (@"%d",index);
```

I have defined in the same way "caloriesImportesD" and "caloriesDepensees".

Any idea for this disfunction ?

Comment: So what is `tabBarController.selectedIndex` inside the `didSelectViewController` method? - An alternative would be to use `isKindOf` to check the class of the passed view controller.

Comment: The selectIndex is 0.
In fact, didSelectViewController works only with tap on the tabbar and so it doesn't works for the first appearance on the tabbar. 
However what I displays in my viewControllers is only "read" the first time. That's why I can't use the "caloriesImportesD".
Any idea to transfer this value to DrinksViewController before the first appearance of TabBarController ?

Comment: Then I do not understand why `if(tabBarController.selectedIndex == 0)`  does not work. Did you type `=` instead of `==`?

Comment: Code I post here is a copy-and-paste of my original code so the "==" is OK.
My problem is to transfer my data earlier so my CollectionView (present in my DrinksViewController) can read "caloriesImportesD".

Comment: OK, so your main problem is not what to do if a tab is selected, but how to "set up" the different view controller? You could do that in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`.

Comment: I can't use `applicationDidFinishLaunching` because the data I want to transfer to my `DrinksViewController` is calculated with my first ViewController.
I don't know how to pass this data now.
'prepareForSegue' is not working because I'm using a ÙITabBarController`and TabBar segues are not "usual".
I don't succeed neither with `didSelectViewController`because I received my data too late.
I try this :
`DrinksViewController *dvc = [[DrinksViewController alloc] init];
dvc.caloriesImportesD = 456;`
But it doesn't work currently. I don't know why.
Any ideas to transfer data ?

Comment: Well I am pretty confused now. What is your first view controller? Where is the data calculated and where is it needed? Perhaps you can sketch your view controllers hierarchy and the transitions.

Comment: So I assume that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18165514/new-ways-to-transfer-data-between-view-controllers was your "real problem"?

Comment: Yes, it appears this was my real problem. Thanks for your help and understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the delegate method only once, it will be called each time one
of the tab items has been selected. Inside the delegate method check which view
controller was selected (e.g. using `tabBarController.selectedIndex`), and act accordingly.
Example:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(TBControllerViewController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    if (tabBarController.selectedIndex == 1) {
        FoodViewController *fvc = (FoodViewController *)viewController;
        fvc.caloriesDepensees = tabBarController.caloriesTB;
    } else {
       // ...
    }
}
```