# New ways to transfer data between view controllers

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, transfer

I have a problem with transferring data between `UIViewController` and I don't find answers in former questions.

**Situation :** I have a first viewController ('CalViewController') which allows users to input data. Then I calculate with those datas a number (named 'calories' for example). The next views are two `UIViewController` (`DrinksViewController` & `FoodViewController`)displayed in a `TabBarController`and I need value of 'calories'.

**What I've tried :**
-`prepareForSegue` method : It doesn't work because segues (symbol in storyboard is a link between two points) in a `TabBarController`are not as others (symbol in storyboard is arrow through a door).

-'didSelectViewController' method : This method is not "activated" to display the first view of a TabBarController. So I succeed to transfer `Calories` to my second ViewController in the TabBarController (ie `FoodViewController`) but not to my first viewController in the TabBarController (ie `DrinksViewController`).

-call the "original" value : Here what I've done in `CalViewController` (after imported `DrinksViewController.h`)

```
DrinksViewController *dvc = [[DrinksViewController alloc] init]; 
dvc.caloriesImported = 456;
```

I don't know why this third way is not working.

**Problem :** My value of `Calories`is not transferred from `CalViewController` to `DrinksViewControlller`. Any ideas ?

Comment: Maybe you could save user input in a plist file and then access data in that file from other view controllers.

Comment: Is CAlViewController also in the tab bar controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, the following should work in the first
view controller `CalViewController`:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"yourSegueToTabBarIdentifier"]) {
        UITabBarController *tbc = [segue destinationViewController];
        DrinksViewController *dvc = tbc.viewControllers[0];
        dvc.caloriesImported = 456;
        FoodViewController *fvc = tbc.viewControllers[1];
        fvc.someProperty = someValue;
    }
}
```

Note that

```
DrinksViewController *dvc = [[DrinksViewController alloc] init]; 
dvc.caloriesImported = 456;
```

cannot work because it allocates a *new* instance of `DrinksViewController` that
is completely unrelated to the instance used by the tab bar controller.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the instances that are already in the tab bar controller. You do that with self.tabBarController.viewControllers[n], where n would be 0,1, or 2 depending on which controller you're trying to access.